# Jquery Autocomplete Search based on each words first char

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Can any one help me on this ?

Autocomplete should be based on first letter of each word in the sentence.

For example

If I am searching for "s"

result should be :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H9ma.gif

The result should be based on the "s" of each words first char on the sentence.

Help me on this..

Thanks in advance.

Tried:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#request").autocomplete({
          source: function(req, responseFn) { 
             var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term); 
             var matcher = new RegExp( "\\b" + re, "i" ); 
             var a = $.grep( charity_names, function(item,index){ 
                return matcher.test(item); 
             });
             responseFn( a ); 
          }, delay:0 
       }); 
    });
```

For Highting the text I have used this code :

/* Autocomplete highlighting */

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, char) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:#333;'>" + char + "</span>";
}
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    this.term = this.term.toLowerCase();
    var resultStr = item.label.toLowerCase();
    var t = "";
    while (resultStr.indexOf(this.term) != -1) {
        var index = resultStr.indexOf(this.term);
        t = t + item.label.replaceAt(index, item.label.slice(index, index + this.term.length));
        resultStr = resultStr.substr(index + this.term.length);
        item.label = item.label.substr(index + this.term.length);
    }
    return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a style='padding:4px 4px; display:block; width:97.3%;'>" + t + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);    
};

/* Autocomplete highlighting Ends here*/
```

Comment: I tried with  below code
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#request").autocomplete({
             source: function(req, responseFn) {
                  var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                  var matcher = new RegExp( "\\b" + re, "i" );
                  var a = $.grep( charity_names, function(item,index){
                      return matcher.test(item);
                  });
                  responseFn( a );
              },
            delay:0             
          });
    });

Comment: What are you using at the backend PHP,Java ??

Comment: In Java Application, But right now I am using the HTML & Jquery for prototype design.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a couple of points on your code:

- You're overcomplicating it a lot. Using a regular expression can greatly simplify your `_renderItem`, and get rid of all those `indexOf` and `substr` calls. In fact, you're already using the regular expression you need in the `source` function.
- At the moment, everything will be turned lowercase. Regex will "magically" solve this for you
- You're discarding everything after the `term` match. Again, regex "magic" does away with this with no additional effort
- It's generally bad practice to directly overwrite library `prototype`s. jQueryUI has an excellent widget factory, and it's *very* easy to use.

So, addressing the above points, you could do something like:

```
$.widget("my.customAutocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>").append(
               $("<a>").html(
                     item.label.replace(
                           new RegExp("\\b" + this.term, "i"),
                           "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:#333;'>$&</span>"
                     )
               )).appendTo(ul);
    }
});
```

Couple this with the `source` filtering you already have to get at what we needed

[Here's an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygnwy5yk/) (with html escaping, too, not sure if that was intentionally omitted in your example or not)